# issues with redux payload in reducers

Tags: javascript, redux

I have the following code for one of the CASES in reducers

```
case CHART_CHANGE: {
            const {method,copiedArray} = payload;

            let ref = copiedArray  
            
            let swapped = bubblesort(copiedArray) //<------here

            console.log(ref)
            console.log(swapped)
          }

      }
```

The question is this, as you can see here I assigned the variable ref before involving the **bubblesort** function. But when I run the program, ref variable has the same value with the swapped variable. Why is that?

Comment: We need for this the code of bubblesort. A piece of working code snippet would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript objects (arrays are objects) are assigned by reference, so `copiedArray` and `ref` are referring (pointing) to the same object. If you change the contents of the object (and your `bubblesort` function seems to sort in place - that is mutate/change the array internally), the changes are visible in all of the variables: `copiedArray`, `ref` and `swapped`.

```js
const copiedArray = [3,2,1];
const ref = copiedArray;
const swapped = copiedArray.sort();

console.log(copiedArray);
console.log(ref);
console.log(swapped);
```

Comment: is there a way through which I can keep a copy of the original array and save it for later use without mutating it?

Comment: @LearnerSamuelX you can do a shallow copy with `slice()`: `ref = copiedArray.slice()` or even better, pass a shallow copy to `bubblesort`: `swapped = bubblesort(copiedArray.slice())`. In this way you'll have unsorted array in `copiedArray` and sorted one in `swapped` - no need for `ref` variable.